# Comparing Means of different Subscales

Tags: statistical-significance, mean, frequentist

a friend recently asked me if she could compare the means in different subscales of one Questionnaire (measuring more or less distinct construct) in one sample.

In concrete she has a sample of 100 people filling out a questionnaire with a anxiety subscale and a depression subscale. She wondered whether the sample had higher anxiety than depression.

I told her that she was comparing apples and oranges.

Is that correct or can she just use an un- or paired t-Test?

In my mind you need two distinct, independent groups (for an unpaired t-test) or multiple measurements /conditions with the same measurement / test in the same people (dependent t-test) to say somethings different. Meaning she could analyze their association ( correlation) but not their disparity, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can compare 'weights' of apples and oranges, because weight means the same thing for both. I suppose also diameters, sugar content, etc. Perhaps, with some care, relative popularity among food buyers.

The question here is whether the anxiety and depression subscales are *comparable.* Perhaps so, if the questions have to do with the extent to which anxiety or depression interferes with everyday activities, job performance, interpersonal relationships, etc.

At least it seems worthwhile to look at the questions on the subscales and to check whether these are well-researched and validated.

If comparable on a numerical scale, perhaps a paired-sample t test would be OK. If not numerical, but comparable on an ordinal scale, perhaps use a paired-sample Wilcoxon (signed-rank) test.

Comment: Hi thanks for your input. Both subscales are build with the sum over the respective likert items they are comprised of. Such sum score in social science are usually treated as interval scaled variables. I think one can always reach numerical comparability by means of linear transformation (multiplying by x so that each subscales ranges from 0 to 100). I am not sure about the 2-sample t-test, since it is only one sample and anxiety and depression are known to have a high correlation. Meaning the mean of the 'sample' anxiety is not indepedent of the mean of the 'sample depression' and vice versa

Comment: Right. Two subscales on a survey taken by the same person would have to be viewed as paired.  If I have the design correctly in mind, you could look for correlation btw anxiety and depression across the 100 subjects. (In view of this, changing last paragraph of Answ.)